# csh script , how to take a command line arg as a literal $argv[1] "*.c" , turn off filename expansion?

Tags: parsing, filenames, csh, expansion

I have a script that is a command line parser , it calls other scripts. One script that it calls is count.s. count.s takes 1 arg and counts words lines chars, it will accept a *.txt and works fine. In the command line parser argv[1] is *.c When I call it from my command line parser , and pass into count.s argv[1], it expands *.c and count.s only reads the first file it enounters. I think I need to take argv[1] , which is a *.whatever and take it as a literal.
How can I do this? I think I need to turn off the filename expansion in the command line parser and pass into count.s the actual *.whatever , instead of the expansion that occurs within the command line parser.

I can post my code if it helps , but I dont think it is really necessary

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't.

The argument `*.c` is expanded by the shell before your script ever sees it.

Suppose the current directory contains `foo.c` and `bar.c`. If you type

```
myscript.csh *.c
```

then `myscript.c` will see `bar.c` and `foo.c` as two separate arguments -- *exactly* as if you had typed

```
myscript.csh bar.c foo.c
```

at the command line.

If you want your script to see the string `*.c`, then you have to pass that as an argument, which you can do by quoting the argument:

```
myscript.csh '*.c'
```

But your script has no control over how and whether wildcards are expanded.

What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: the script count takes 1 arguement , a filename or a wildcard , and coutns words lines chars in that/those files. I have a few other simple scripts as well.... mu.csh parses command line args , so as per the assignment one call is : ./mu.csh -r 3 4 5 -c *.c -f line temp.txt

Comment: so -r figures out if its a right triangle , -c is supposed to count words lines chars in all *.c files.  When I run the count.csh script alone it works fine , but when i call count in the driver program and pass arg[6]  , which is the *.c  it seems like it is already expanded and all it passes to the count script is the first alphabetically listed .c program..

Comment: OK. Does your script actually need to see the literal `*.c`? It seems to me it should just see the list of file names. It shouldn't care whether that list is the result of a wildcard expansion.

Comment: I just added a while loop and passed each individual file that was "found" to count.s  it wasnt pretty but it worked.